# Drive two monitors from 1 USB-C/Thunderbolt (Lenovo/ViewSonic)

Tags: multiple-monitors, displayport, thunderbolt, usb-c, daisychaining

I have a Lenovo X1 Carbon 5th Gen. 
It has 2x USC-C/Thunderbolt ports, plus USB-B and HDMI. 
It supports MST.

I have also 2x ViewSonic VP2468s. 
The displays have DisplayPort (In); miniDisplayPort (In); DisplayPort (Out)

I have connected the Thunderbolt from the laptop to DP-In (1); then daisy-chained DP-Out (1) to DP-In (2).

I briefly had Windows to detecting 3 displays; but now I can only get the 2 external displays to detect and one display and to display the same output.

ViewSoinc have told me that if I drive the first screen from a thunderbolt then both must be. 
Does this make sense? 
I'm not sure I understand the overlap between USC-C, thunderbolt, and DisplayPort. Surely if I can drive one display with a TB-to-DP cable; and the the DP-Out > DP-IN drive an image to the other screen, then I should be able to daisy-chain.

Any ideas where to go next with this?